# Overlay/Transparent window while using a software

Tags: scripts, function-keys

Good day everyone.

I'm a Front-End developer that recently switched to ubuntu/pop!os (around two months).

Getting familiar little by little to Linux (so many opportunity to tweak my workflow)!

My question/issue is the next one:

While coding with VSCode i would like to be able to use a F-Key (eg: F10) to open a file (on-top/overlay of the VScode window) and by pressing it again (eg: F10) closing this file/new window.

The file would be a .MD or .txt of some sort.

Knowing that Linux is quite "free" for tweaking i was wondering if someone would know a way to do so? (Or is it even possible?)

Thank you for taking the time to read my issue.

-Bone

Comment: Not sure I get the idea, a transparent window (. txt/. md??) on top of the vs window? With what purpose?

Comment: Simply reading the file itself.

The idea would be to write some information that i usually need, instead of having to alt-tab to the open file (that force me to switch between vscode and the file that i want to open).

i would like to use a f-key to open that file and close it.

Comment: As an example when i use the SUPER KEY , i have the launcher that pop-up. I'd like to use the F10 to kind of have the same behaviour but a text file instead.